# tort law - loss of employment after psychiatric injury

Tags: england-and-wales, negligence

**X** suffered psychiatric injury by the negligence of **Y**. 
**X** remains sick a year after wards and jobless as well.

Is **Y** liable for psychiatric injury only (assuming he is negligent) or is he liable for **X**'s future employment-loss as well?
Jurisdiction is England.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **X** would be hard-pressed to demonstrate that joblessness was a harm caused by negligence.  A large number of people who are benefiting from psychiatric support and care are also jobless.

At very least it may not be **X**'s core claim, which may then undermine the viability of the suit.

*. not speaking specifically for the UK, but the US is also a common-law jurisdiction .*

Answer (score 0):

If **X** can prove that the injury is a result of **Y**'s negligence then **Y** is liable for the damage that is a reasonably foreseeable result of that negligence. So, maybe.

Comment: any case law reference please?